# How to map a json to entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have the json below:

```
{
"script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.PARAM = VALUE"
},
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "fields": ["kpi","weekday","hour"],
        "query": "(kpi:'KPI') AND (weekday:'WEEKDAY') AND (hour:'HOUR')"
    }
}
```

}

I need to send this json to a post request. I´m trying to represent this json acoording below:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
map.put("script", new HashMap<String, String>());
map.get("script").put("source", "ctx._source.PARAM = " + valor);
    
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> map2 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>();
map2.put("query", new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>());
map2.get("query").put("query_string", new HashMap<String, String>());
map2.get("query").get("query_string").put("fields", "[\"kpi\",\"weekday\",\"hour\"]");
map2.get("query").get("query_string").put("query", "(kpi:'" + kpi +"') AND (weekday:'" + weekday +"') AND (hour:'" + hour +"')");
```

The problem is that the structured above is separated in two variables (map and map2). I need this structure in only one variable (map).

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise the Object type in the map to be able to combine the two maps as such:

```
Map<String, Object> joinedMap = new HashMap<>();

//map 1
Map<String, String> scriptMap = new HashMap<>();
scriptMap.put("source", "ctx._source.PARAM = " + valor);

joinedMap.put("script", scriptMap);

//map 2
Map<String, Map<String, String>> queryMap = new HashMap<>();
queryMap.put("query_string", new HashMap<String, String>());
queryMap.get("query_string").put("fields", "[\"kpi\",\"weekday\",\"hour\"]");
queryMap.get("query_string").put("query", "(kpi:'" + kpi +"') AND (weekday:'" + weekday +"') AND (hour:'" + hour +"')");

joinedMap.put("query", queryMap);
```

Consider using a POJO to encapsulate this object so you can convert the JSON string to a java object, manipulate the variables, then convert back to a json string.

Comment: It doesn´t work. The Eclipse shows error on the put and get commands: "The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type Object"

Comment: Pls see the updated edit. The reason is that an Object doesnt have those methods, they are part of map interface. So you cant call those functions on Object without parsing them to a Map object first. Instead I redone the answer so that you generate the sub maps and then add them to the joined maps at the end.